# How to access instance_variables of a class and why does this method call return nil?

Tags: ruby

```
class Human
  @core = "heart"

  def cardiovascular
    arr = ['heart','blood','lungs']
    core = @core
  end
end
```

Is the only way I am able to access `@core` directly by using this:

```
Human.instance_variable_get(:@core)  #=> "heart"
```

My understanding is that an *instance variable* is accessible from anywhere within the *scope* of the *Class*.

I am able to access the *method* by: `Human.new.cardiovascular` and I expect the return to be `"heart"` but the return I get is `nil`

1. How come I can't access the *instance variable* as `Human.core` or `Human.new.core`?
2. Why does the `Human.new.cardiovascular` return `nil`? (Shouldn't core == @core?)

**Update**

After putting `@core` within an initialize block I see the following output in IRB:

```
Human.new
=> #<Human:0x2f1f030 @core="heart">
```

This makes sense as it's now available to the entire *Class*, but how do I access the specific *instance variables* within the initialize block? Meaning, how do I get just: `@core` without calling the `cardiovascular` method in this case?

Comment: using this http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor

Comment: Thanks @Arup, I see adding: `attr_accessor :core` Allows me to access `@core` as `Human.new.core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also..

> How come I can't access the instance variable as Human.core or Human.new.core?

Because, in Ruby, *only* methods can be accessed as such - not variables/fields. In this aspect, Ruby acts like SmallTalk (and unlike Python, Java, and many other OOP languages). The "accessor" (e.g. `attr_accessor`) methods create applicable proxies.

> Why does the Human.new.cardiovascular return nil? (Shouldn't core == @core?)

Because `@core` in context is `nil` as explained in the other answers (and observations), however, the assignment `core = @core` is useless in the context (and this ties in with the previous question) because the local variable assignments are only accessible within that scope.

Note the correctness of the observation(s) - e.g. `Human.instance_variable_get(:@core)` works because it is an instance variable for the receiver (the `Human` class which is also an object), even if not for any instance of said class. Continue with this logic analysis, it's right :)

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
class Human
  def initialize
    @core = "heart"
  end

  def cardiovascular
    arr = ['heart','blood','lungs']
    core = @core
  end
end
```

In short, you're setting instance variable on a class itself (which is an object too), but you want it on an instance.